# Update computed column, convert VARCHAR to BIT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a database that stores boolean fields as VARCHAR(1) ('T' or 'F'). I want to replace these with BIT. The problem is that this would require a ton of changes in the program that uses the database. So I thought the logical step is to add a BIT field and replace the existing VARCHAR(1) field with a computed column that I access rather than accessing the BIT field (thus the program can continue to work as is without changes, and be changed to use the BIT field over time).

I know this won't work (UPDATE and INSERT doesn't work on computed columns). I know one option is to rename the existing table and add a view through which to access it, but I don't see that as a viable solution, as adding and removing columns, changing dependent views, etc. would be prone to errors (and it's not a neat solution in my opinion).

My question is - what are my options to achieve the above behaviour (such that the program can continue working as is)?

An example:

```
User (Active VARCHAR(1), ...)
```

Changed to use computed columns: (won't work)

```
User (Active_B BIT, Active AS CASE Active_B WHEN 1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END, ...)
```

**UPDATE:** Fixed error in example.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have the cake and eat it too. You already stated the solution(s), with all its shortcomings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to have both a VARCHAR and a BIT field and use triggers to update between them.

I'll just have to figure out how to prevent infinite recursion (one idea is to have a field that serves no other purpose than to check if this trigger resulted from an update within another trigger (check if we're updating it and include it in the update in the trigger)). The updates need to go both ways to allow for easy backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.User
ADD Active AS CASE Active_B WHEN 1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END PERSISTED
```

You need to use the **column name** (not the datatype) in the `CASE`. And I'd recommend making the computed column **persisted**, too - so that the value gets actually stored on disk (and not recomputed every time you access it).

Comment: I just made a mistake in my example. This still doesn't solve my problem, as INSERT and DELETE queries won't work (on the VARCHAR field).

Comment: @Dukeling: then you additionally need `INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE` triggers to "catch" those cases and handle them

Comment: With an INSTEAD OF trigger I'll probably have to do some rather complicated stuff to get it to exclude Active and include Active_B in the query (and keep all other fields the same), right?

Comment: @Dukeling: yes - which begs the question - why not just leave it as is? The effort do change it seems bigger than the benefit you get from changing it.... you *could* at least make it a `CHAR(1)` column so it'll use up 1 byte (instead of 3, for the `VARCHAR(1)`, because of the 2-byte overhead for it's variable length...)